# Formatting non-R code from variable in RStudio notebook

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

In rmarkdown I can format sql code from variable as follow:

````
```{r a, echo=FALSE}
sql_string <- "select 1 as a_column, 'asdasd' as b_column
from the.tmp.database
where x > 14 and date_of_a < '2015-01-10'
order by value"
```

Some sql code:

```sql
`r sql_string`
```
````

To achieve the same in [Rstudio notebook](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebook_format.html) I need to use "hack" solution:

````
#+ a, echo=FALSE
sql_string <- "select 1 as a_column, 'asdasd' as b_column
from the.tmp.database
where x > 14 and date_of_a < '2015-01-10'
order by value"

#' Some sql code:
#' ```sql
#' `r sql_string`
#' ```
````

Is this the right way or I lack knitr/spin/etc. knowledge?

I expected that I will be able to do something like:

```
#+ printing_code, magic_command=TRUE
# or:
#+ printing_code, results=highlight
sql_string / print(sql_string) / cat(sql_string)
```

so code will be shown both in interactive session and in compiled notebook.

Comment: what is the hack exactly

Comment: @rawr clarified in question